# GeckoFX: Cast GeckoNode to GeckoHTMLElement

Tags: c#, dom, casting, geckofx

I simply need to do a Click on the first Child of an Element identified by a unique Class.

My Code so far is:

```
geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("button")[0].FirstChild.Click();
```

The Problem is that GeckoFX 16's `geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName` returns an Array of the Type `GeckoNode`, which doesnt have the Click Method, so this Code wouldnt work. On the other side, the Method
`geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByName`
returns an Array of the Type `GeckoHTMLElement`, which does have a Click Method.
 Based on that fact, I tried casting with the `as` Operator, but this always throws an Exception with the message that it cant be casted. 
 I searched already alot in GeckoFX's Classes(sadly there isnt any documentation), but I dont found anything
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before casting you need to ensure the node is actually an element, and not, for example, a text node.

```
GeckoNode node = geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("button")[0].FirstChild;
if (NodeType.Element == node.NodeType)
{
  GeckoElement element = (GeckoElement)node;
  element.Click();
}
else
{
 // Even though GetElementByClassName return type could contain non elements, I don't think
 // it ever would in reality.
 Console.WriteLine("First node is a {0} not an element.", node.NodeType);
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider adding some text to describe your solution. e.g. *Just check the node type to see if node type it is*

Comment: Your code always said tht it isnt a geckoelement, but I already by executing javascript, selecting the element by querySelectorAll, giving it a unique class name and then clicking over geckofx

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if html has already been loaded?

Try running this code after the DocumentCompleted event occurs.

```
geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Here you can add the coding to perform after document loaded
   GeckoInputElement txtbox = (GeckoInputElement)geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtBox1");
   txtbox.SetAttribute("value","OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GeckoElement does not support Click, but GeckoHtmlElement.

geckoWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsBy... does not return GeckoHtmlElement, only GeckoElement(s); So sad!

Comment: GetHtmlElementById exists as well as GetElementById